# What does num>>1 mean in c++?

Tags: c++

I know this is a very simple question, but I'm having trouble finding the answer on google as it ignores the "<<" characters. If you have any advice for how I should search for things like this in the future that would also be much appreciated. I seem to recall its some kind of bitshift or something? But I don't really know what that means or how it works whether its just -1 or something else as if it is I don't know why the person wouldn't just use -1. Thanks

Comment: *"I seem to recall its some kind of bitshift or something?"* -- And you didn't try searching for that?  It's much more google friendly than `>>`, expecially if you append `c++` to it.

Comment: Read this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: Ya I didn't realize I remembered it had something to do with bitshift until I was already writing that sentence which was towards the end so I felt committed to the post. Sorry for that. What are the advantages of using it though as it seems much harder to understand what its doing as you have to convert it to binary first in your head. Oh sorry is it just the same thing as dividing by 2 but faster? Jk I now noticed the top voted answer below this which explains it.

Comment: @emschorsch: It is no faster than dividing by 2 on a modern compiler. But, it depends on the abstraction you're working with. Sometimes it makes sense to think of your integer as a bunch of bits, and sometimes it makes sense to think of it as a number. The choice of `>>` vs. `/ 2` all depends on what would make more sense to think about in context. When compilers were dumber, it was frequently faster. But, as I said, most compilers are smart enough now to optimize a divide by a power of 2 into a bitshift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It ('`>>`') means 'right shift' in a context where the left-hand operand is an integral type.  For unsigned types, `uvalue >> 1` is equivalent to dividing by two and truncating the value; it drops the least significant bit, moves every other bit down one place, and inserts a 0 in the most significant bit.  For signed types and positive values, the behaviour is the same; if the value is negative, the behaviour is at best implementation-defined.

If the left-hand operand is an input stream, then it is an input operation (but you can't input to a literal such as `1`, but you could to a variable such as `l`).

Similarly, '`<<`' means 'left shift' in a context where the left-hand operand is an integral type, and it means an output operation when the left-hand operand is an output stream.

Of course, if the left-hand operand is a class, then the operation means whatever the class defines the operation to mean.  The I/O streams are a specific special case of 'what the class defines the operation to mean'.

Note that if the LH operand is an integer of N bits (when promoted if its type is shorter than `int`), then it is only valid to shift by a RH value that is between 0 and N-1; any larger or smaller shift yields undefined behaviour.  Note, in particular, that shifting by N is undefined behaviour.

The comment about classes and I/O streams do not apply to C, but where the operands are both integers, the behaviour in C is the same as in C++.

Comment: Ya sorry the lefthand is an integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary right-shift of `num` by one place. There is a very good [tutorial here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

Example which would help : 
`int m=16; //(10000) n=m>>1; //n=(01000)` resulting in `n=8` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Both `<<` and `>>` are shift operators.  See the following for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`<< N` shifts the bits in a numeric value to the left by N.  `>> N` to the right.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Unsigned_bit_shift_operator